# Solve $f(x)=f(\log x)+1$

Tags: logarithms, functional-equations

I was wondering how many times can we take the $\log$ of a given number. Does this number have a closed form? If so, what is it?

**My try:**
I defined a function $f\colon\mathbb R^+\to\mathbb N$, which is our desired answer. Then, we get the following recursion and initial condition.
\begin{gather}
f(x)=f(\log x)+1\\
f(x)=1\forall x\in(0,1]
\end{gather}
Any ideas?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iterated_logarithm it is noted $\log^*$.

Comment: So there is no closed form, @zwim?

Comment: No, we just define a new function.

Comment: OK Thanks, Please post it as an answer, I'll accept it.